# Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 started to ask for elevation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I worked fine in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 under Windows 7 64-bit, but after some time VS-2010 started to ask for elevation each launch.

Yep, it works fine. But running in administrator mode each time is somehow unconfident.

Googling doesn't help spread the light on the problem; I hope fellow developers have faced and solved this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a wild guess: Maybe the "Run as administrator" flag is set on the shortcut?

Right click -> Properties -> Advanced -> "Run as administrator"

Comment: Oh!... After you posted this, I decided to come again through all the properties. Properties -> Shortcut -> Advanced -> "Run as Administrator" was unset; However Properties -> Compatibility -> "Run as Administrator" (another one just found there :) ) was.

This fixed the problem.

However, I don't know how it does appear there.
Thank you :)

Comment: That is indeed odd.  Glad the guess paid off, though!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a plain installation of VS 2010 would ask for admin rights, Did you install any extensions lately? may be one of them needs admin access for some reason?